# Return JSON Array Websockets data feed

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying to get the message that is being returned by and apparently it is more of a

```
<function on_message at 0x00000138D6488F28>
```

How can I get it to return json message instead of the one above?

Below is my code.

```
from websocket import WebSocketApp
from json import dumps, loads
from pprint import pprint

URL = "wss://ws-feed.gdax.com"

def on_message(_, message):
    pprint(loads(message))
    print

def on_open(socket):
    params = {
        "type": "subscribe",
        "channels": [{"name": "ticker", "product_ids": ["BTC-EUR"]}]
    }
    socket.send(dumps(params))

def main():
    ws = WebSocketApp(URL, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
    while True:
        print(ws.on_message)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def on_message(_, message): # this will be called everytime a message is recieved
    pprint(loads(message))
    print

def main():
    ws = WebSocketApp(URL, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message)
    ws.run_forever() # this will run the ws main_loop that is builtin and listen for the connection and messages
```

ps thats a cool ws service ... I always enjoy finding new public ws services

Comment: I had used it, but I didn't archive what I was looking for since it only streams data after every 5 seconds yet I am looking for data after every second or less.

Comment: Hello, thanks.... Your answer worked. I also have another question... wanna give it a try? [just follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747350/how-can-i-loop-a-constantly-moving-variable-within-a-timeframe-of-x-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it prints `function`, because you literally are printing out the function, not calling it. But that function is not meant to be called by you, but it will be called by the `WebSocketApp` when you actually have a message and someone has connected to your socket.

If you, however, really want to call it, you can probably just do it by changing `print(ws.on_message)` to `ws.on_message(None, 'your message')`.

Comment: he is the client not the server :P

Comment: Ah yes, missed that small bit... Well, point is still exactly the same, doesn't matter which way the connection happens. :D

Comment: Well, I cannot use `ws.on_message(None, 'your message')` since it is supposed to return a message. of which I am most interested in. So how can I go about it?

Comment: @Muema Well but that's the thing, the server has to submit the message for you to see it. Having `print(message)` in the `on_message` function should be enough, but you have to connect to the server, keep the socket open with `run_forever` and wait for the server to post a message.

Comment: @wanaryytel sorry this is the old thread which got answered, I raised similar question, but my issue is  how to return the "print(message)" out of WS function so that I can return it