# Gdax Candle Stick using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anyone here with an idea of how to loop a constantly moving variable within a timeframe of 60 seconds to check it's highest, medium, lowest and average of the three?

Then creating more of a json objects of the past minutes

Tried using timer for custom threading and seems that it is not working for me

Below is my code. Kindly assist.

```
import sys, getopt
import time
from threading import Timer
import main.botlog as botlog
from main.settings import auth_client,product



class BotCandlestick(object):

def __init__(self, period=60, open=None, close=None, high=None, low=None, priceAverage=None):
    self.current = None
    self.open = open
    self.close = close
    self.high = high
    self.low = low
    self.startTime = time.time()
    self.period = period
    BotLog = botlog.BotLog
    self.output = BotLog()
    self.priceAverage = priceAverage


def tick(self, price):
    # while True:

    self.current = float(price)
    if (self.open is None):
        self.open = self.current
        print(self.open)

    if ((self.high is None) or (self.current > self.high)):
        self.high = self.current
        print(self.high)

    if ((self.low is None) or (self.current < self.low)):
        self.low = self.current
        print(self.low)

    if (time.time() >= (self.startTime + self.period)):
        self.close = self.current
        self.priceAverage = (self.high + self.low + self.close) / float(3)
        print(self.priceAverage)

    self.output.log(
        "Open: " + str(self.open) + " Close: " + str(self.close) + " High: " + str(self.high) + " Low: " + str(
            self.low) + " Current: " + str(self.current))



def isClosed(self):
    if (self.close is not None):
        return True
    else:
        return False




def main():
    price = auth_client.get_product_ticker(product)
    prices = float(price.get('price'))
    price = BotCandlestick()
    d = price.tick(prices)
    t = Timer(10.0, d)
    t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out a universal way to go about this problem. Kindly find the code below. It is more of a universal code to find value change within x time.

```
import gdax
import time
public = gdax.PublicClient()


while True:
    endtime = time.time() + 60
    x = []
    while time.time() < endtime:
        ticker = public.get_product_ticker('BTC-USD')
        ticker = ticker['price']
        ticker = float(ticker)
        x.append(ticker)
        change = ((x[0]-x[-1])/x[-1])

        print(ticker)

        time.sleep(1)
    print("Open: {}  High: {}  Low:  {}  Close: {}  Change: {}%".format(x[0], max(x), min(x), x[-1], change*100))
    time.sleep(0)
```